# Merging screen recordings without resampling

Tags: video, quicktime

cmd+shift+5 is incredible for screen recording!

Splitting a screen recording without resampling the video is easy with quicktime - `Edit/Trim` the first part and save, then reopen the original recording, `Edit/Trim` the second part and save. These save super-fast, a testament to simply being copied rather than resampled.

But what if I'd like to merge (concatenate) two screen recordings without resampling?
Using quicktime's `Edit/Add Clip to End` seems to force a resampling and takes 10x longer to save. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a command line tool called ffmpeg, which can be installed with any package manager such as brew or macports.

You can use `concat` option of ffmpeg like this:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i listofvideos.txt -c copy output.mov
```

Contents of listofvideos.txt:

```
file 'movie1.mov'
file 'movie2.mov'
file 'movie3.mov'
```

`-c copy` makes sure the codec is copied and nothing is resampled.
More info about concat can be found [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Comment: Thank you. What are the parameters "-safe" and -f "for?

Comment: `-safe 0` is to be able to use absolute paths or filenames with spaces in them in listofvideos.txt, `-f concat` is for forcing the `concat` demuxer.

Comment: unfortunately I have a work Macbook so I'm unable to run executables downloaded from the web and can't run package managers, however I can install apps, so I'm still looking for a solution for this

Comment: @Jonathan what about HandBrake? I suppose you can also do it under that.